# Spring @GetMapping returning empty array

Tags: java, spring, rest, get

When use GET with postman on link  http://localhost:8081/api/data/mydatas/admin

i get an empty array. I've also tried adding
{ "username": "admin" } but it still returns as an empty array.

this is the code in my java service:

```
@GetMapping("/mydatas/{username}")
    public List<Data> findByUsername(String username) {

        Query q = em.createQuery("select data from Data data where data.username = :username");
        q.setParameter("username", username);
        List<Data> mydatas = q.getResultList();
        return mydatas;
        
        }
```

However, if i add username = "admin"; as below. It will send back the array with full of data.

```
    @GetMapping("/mydatas/{username}")
    public List<Data> findByUsername(String username) {

        username = "admin";

        Query q = em.createQuery("select data from Data data where data.username = :username");
        q.setParameter("username", username);
        List<Data> mydatas = q.getResultList();
        return mydatas;
        
        }
```

What am i doing wrong? Ps i am a novice still struggling with the basics.

Comment: Try to add @PathVariable to your parameter username.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add @PathVariable before your parameter like so

```
@PathVariable String username
```

With this annotation you are telling Spring to grab username from URL path

Answer (score 2):

You need to use @PathVariable,

```
public List<Data> findByUsername(@PathVariable("username") String username)
```

Answer (score 0):

The @PathVariable annotation should be passed in with the name of the field in speechmarks "" as the argument for findByUsername before "String username"